# Is $(1,0,0,0,...,0)$ a legitimate dividend stream?

Tags: option-pricing

A book I am reading defines a positive linear functional as a "price functional" from a set of adapted processes to the real numbers. Specifically, it defines a "consistent price functional" as one that gives the value zero to every dividend stream corresponding to any trading strategy. However, it also says that the value of the process $(1,0,0,0,....)$ can be set to $1$.

Then that means this process is NOT a dividend stream corresponding to some trading strategy. Why not?

EDIT: It's from page 59 of [this notes](http://www.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/fin1/ifnotes.pdf).